# autocompletebox cursor issue

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am using Silverlight's AutoCompleteBox control in my application. It works great except that after choosing the required item, the cursor is set at the end of the text. If the length of the selected text is too long, user has to scroll to the beginning of the box to see what exactly was selected. How do I get the cursor to be set at the beginning of the text instead of the end?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the following implementation.

[Silverlight AutoCompleteBox uppercase input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705049/silverlight-autocompletebox-uppercase-input/6707408#6707408)