# Silverlight AutoCompleteBox uppercase input

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to force uppercase input inside AutoCompleteBox in Silverlight 4 app.

In TextBox this could be done by replacing Text property on KeyDown event like:

```
            control.Text += enteredChar;
            control.Select(control.Text.Length, 0); //To maintain caret position
```

However AutoCompleteBox doesn't provide text selection function, and I found no way to move caret to string end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change AutoCompleteBox template and add UpperCaseBehavior to the TextBox within:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Text" ...>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:UpperCaseBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

where UpperCaseBehavior is:

```
public class UpperCaseBehavior: Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += AssociatedObject_TextChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var selectionStart = AssociatedObject.SelectionStart;
        var selectionLength = AssociatedObject.SelectionLength;

        AssociatedObject.Text = AssociatedObject.Text.ToUpper();

        AssociatedObject.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
        AssociatedObject.SelectionLength = selectionLength;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= AssociatedObject_TextChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

Comment: this will work, but with a filtering bug due to text cursor position changing, one of our developers tries this path, and there was a small bug, I don't remember exectly but it was related to not selected item from autocomplete list when the text exectly match list item, due to some event not firing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use binding and convert the typed value to uppercase immediately. Add a custom style to have the textchanged event. I tested this, so if you need I can send you a sample if you don't manage to get it working.

XAML:

Add a resource:

```
<Style x:Key="AutoCompleteBoxStyle1" TargetType="sdk:AutoCompleteBox">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="45"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:AutoCompleteBox">
                            <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PopupStates">
                                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="PopupOpened"/>
                                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="PopupClosed"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PopupOpened">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PopupClosed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <TextBox x:Name="Text" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" IsTabStop="True" Margin="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" SelectionChanged="Text_SelectionChanged"/>
                                <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                            <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                        <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </EventTrigger>
                                            </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        </ToolTip>
                                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                                        <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                        <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                                    <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                                        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderThickness="0" Background="#11000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0">
                                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
                                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="1.0" Padding="0">
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#AADDDDDD" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Border.Background>
                                                <Border.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="-1"/>
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </Border.RenderTransform>
                                                <ListBox x:Name="Selector" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Add your AutoCompleteBox and reference the previous style:

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox Width="169" x:Name="txtSearchBox" Text="{Binding TypedText, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxStyle1}" />
```

Code Behind:

Bind the typed text:

```
private string _typedText;
public string TypedText
{
    get { return _typedText; }
    set
    {
        _typedText = value.ToUpper();
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TypedText");
    }
}
```

The TextSelection event:

```
private void Text_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
            if (tb != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TypedText) && tb.SelectionStart != TypedText.Length)
            {
                tb.SelectionStart = TypedText.Length;
                tb.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
        }
```

HTH

Comment: I will try this, basically you get a reference to internal TextBox wich AutoCompelete wraps, but i dont think that messing with its selection functionality is a good thing to do, becouse it will interfere with it's own autocompelete append selecton, but this is only assumption, thank you I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't perfect, but it works! on lost focus event put the text in upper case

```
<pre>
private void AutoCompleteTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var a = (AutoCompleteTextBox)sender;
  a.Text = a.Text.ToUpper();
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up, creating font with only capital latters and using it.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN: AutoCompleteBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795156%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#customizing_the_appearance_of_the_autocompletebox)

Basically just use a style setter on the TextBox.CharacterCasing property as
follows:

```
    <my:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="autoCompleteBox1">
        <my:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper" />
            </Style>
        </my:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
    </my:AutoCompleteBox>
```

This avoids the hassle of then having to hack a solution to the caret position problem when adjusting the case of the text.

There are other options for where and how to setup the Style and Setter of course (I've forgotten the ins and outs but the above seemed to get the job done)

NB: I'm using this in WPF .Net v4.0, with an AutoCompleteBox that does an async list populate (no filtering is done by the control).